# Linux /proc/kallsyms file, where does kernel save core symbols list?

Tags: c, assembly, module, linux-kernel, symbols

To display symbols in `/proc/kallsyms`, for the module symbols, kernel loops over module objects headed by `modules` kernel variable, and iterate over each module's symbol table. But for the 'core' kernel built-in symbols, it uses a bunch of kernel variables, demonstrated in this function:

```
static unsigned long kallsyms_sym_address(int idx)
{
    if (!IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_KALLSYMS_BASE_RELATIVE))
        return kallsyms_addresses[idx];

    /* values are unsigned offsets if --absolute-percpu is not in effect */
    if (!IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ABSOLUTE_PERCPU))
        return kallsyms_relative_base + (u32)kallsyms_offsets[idx];

    /* ...otherwise, positive offsets are absolute values */
    if (kallsyms_offsets[idx] >= 0)
        return kallsyms_offsets[idx];

    /* ...and negative offsets are relative to kallsyms_relative_base - 1 */
    return kallsyms_relative_base - 1 - kallsyms_offsets[idx];
}
```

Questions are:

1. where are kallsyms_addresses and kallsyms_offsets arrays defined? I tried to grep in kernel source but only find references, no definitions.
2. where are they initialized?
3. what's the relation between these variables and /boot/System.map.kernel_version file? I assume they should be consistent but again I didn't find the initialization code.

Comment: I don't know the exact answers but am fairly sure there must be linker magic involved. You may want to trace through scripts/kallsysms.c which appears to be constructing those symbols (and others) at link time.

Comment: See [scripts/kallsyms.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kallsyms.c) and [scripts/link-vmlinux.sh](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/link-vmlinux.sh)

Comment: Thanks guys, the hints explained a lot. One thing I still don't understand - if `nm -n vmlinux` works, does that mean there is already a symbol table in the temporary vmlinux binary? If so, why can't one use this symtab directly, instead of using kallsyms.c and link-vmlinux.sh to patch another symbol table generated from `nm`?