# What does value of 'current_task' mean in different version of linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, task

I know that `current_task` holds the address of `task_struct *` pointer for each cpu.

However, when reading this symbol value in different kernel version, I got diverse result.

In `4.19.65` kernel, I grabbed it by `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep current_task` and got:

```
0000000000015c40 A current_task
```

which means it is an absolute value.

In `4.20.13` kernel, I got:

```
ffffffffbea3a040 D current_task
```

which means it is in data section.

I used default config for `4.19.65` kernel. However, I have not got config file for `4.20.13`. 
I'm wondering if the value meaning is related to kernel version or kernel configuration? When it holds an absolute value, how does kernel find `current_task` pointer?

Comment: In both kernel versions `current_task` is a [per-cpu variable](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c#L1522) defined with `DEFINE_PER_CPU` macro. So the difference is most likely in how `kallsyms` output such variables. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146865/linux-proc-kallsyms-file-where-does-kernel-save-core-symbols-list) and `KALLSYMS_ABSOLUTE_PERCPU` configuration option for the Linux kernel.